# array of linked list for hash table

Tags: c

I want to know about bring the text file with 10 names and read it. 10 names are sorting by descending and forming a hash table with division method. I need to construct linked list of them. The hash table's index is number of 7.

I've tried on match pointer variable and made a hash table, but I can't do that. I'm in trouble with making hash table, inserting data, printing hash table and searching data(A function to find when I type a name.). I need to add more function..how do i made it?

```
#define SIZE 7


struct node {
   char data[100][20];
   struct node* next; 
}; 

struct index {
   struct node* head; 
   int count; 
};



struct sum (data){ 
   struct node* ptr;

   int sum,i;
   for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    ptr -> data[i] = ptr;
    strcpy(sum,ptr);
   }

  return sum;   
};


int hashFunction (int sum) { 

    return sum%SIZE; 
}



void descend (data) { 

    int temp;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
       for(j=0;j=20;j++) {
         if (data[i][j+1]>data[i][j])
            temp=data[i][j];
            data[i][j]=data[i][j+1];
            data[i][j+1]=temp;
         }
    }   
}



int main (void) {

    char data[100][20];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        fscanf (fp,"%s",&data);
        printf("%s\n",data);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    hashTable = (struct index*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(struct index));
    descend(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this `fscanf (fp,"%s",&data)` should be `fscanf (fp,"%s",&data[i])` as `data` is 2D array.

Comment: There are so many errors in that code, please compile asking for all the warnings and look at the errors and warning produced by your compiler to fix them

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of bugs in the code, I'm just putting my possible observation. Firstly this

```
fscanf (fp,"%s",&data);
```

should be

```
fscanf (fp,"%s",&data[i]);
```

Secondly, here in `descend()` function inner loop condition part you are using `j=20` which loops to run infinitely. This is where MACRO comes handy as this `j=20` simply runs i.e if it could have `ROW=j` where `ROW` is `20` compiler produces meaningful  error. This

```
void descend (data) { /* what is the tyep of data ?  you should mention the data type */ 
    int temp;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) { /* there are only 20 lines not 100 i.e it should be i<20 */
       for(j=0;j=20;j++) { /* condition is wrong, you indented for j<20 but that too
                             wrong as there are supposed to be max 100 char in line 
                             it should be j<100 */
         if (data[i][j+1]>data[i][j]) /* condition is not correct */
            temp=data[i][j];
            data[i][j]=data[i][j+1];
            data[i][j+1]=temp;
         }
    }   
}
```

Correct version `descend` function can be

```
void descend (char (*data)[ROW], int col) {  /* define ROW as macro with value 20 and pass the col i.e 100 */

    int temp;
    for(i=0;i < ROW; i++) {
       for(j=0;j < col; j++) {
         if (data[i][j] > data[i][j+1])
            temp = data[i][j];
            data[i][j] = data[i][j+1];
            data[i][j+1] = temp;
         }
    }   
}
```

Also check the return value of `fopen()` to check whether it was success r failed and do proper validation. For e.g

```
fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
if(fp == NULL) {
   /* @TODO error handling */
   fprintf(stderr,"file doesn't exist");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, it looks like you should declare `char data[20][100]` instead of `char data[100][20]`.

Then, inside the loop of 20 iterations, you should refer to `data[i]` instead of `data`:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    fscanf(fp,"%s",data[i]);
    printf("%s\n",data[i]);
}
```

Keep in mind you're assuming that each line in your input file is at most 99-character long.

This doesn't answer the actual question I suppose, but you should by the least get all the above fixed.